# Using belongs_to in both Parent Controller and Child Controller does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inherited-resources

I have a a scenario where I had to use belongs_to association in a Parent Controller as well as Child Controller.  In this scenario, the helpers like collection_url are generating wrong and I get undefined method....

Below is my scenario..

```
class ProjectController < InheritedResources::Base
class JavaProjectController < ProjectController

class TaskController < InheritedResources::Base
  belongs_to :project
end

class JavaTaskController < TaskController
  belongs_to :java_project
end
```

In this above scenario, when I tried to generate `<%= collection_url %>` inside my view under `JavaTaskController`, I get the following error :

```
NoMethodError ... java_project_java_project_java_tasks_url
```

If the `collection_url` is called in the context of `TaskController`, everything works fine.
However, if I comment out the `belongs_to` association in the `TaskController`, now the `collection_url` works fine when running in the context of `JavaTaskController`.

What am I missing?  Is this a bug or limitation?  Or Am I doing something silly?

Any help in this regard would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. If I specify the belongs_to in the class directly inheriting from InheritedResources::Base, it works fine. But when I move it to a controller which inherits from that, it breaks as you describe.